# I have a canvas that I am trying to send the dataURL with javascript to php using ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a page with a canvas.  I'm using signaturPad to capture a signature.  I now need to send this signature to the php page to process and save

```
var saveButton = document.getElementById('save');
var cancelButton = document.getElementById('clear');

saveButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {




var canvas = document.getElementById('signature-pad');
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
console.log(dataURL);

$.ajax({

    type: "POST",

    url: "user_group_start_paperwork_esign2.php?group_id=1389",

    data: dataURL,

    //dataType: "html",

    cache: false,

    success: function(data){//console.log(data)



    }

    });
```

And on the PHP side

```
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/');
    $img = $_POST['data'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

But I don't seem to be sending anything.  The console.log is getting the data but the $_POST['data'] seems to be empty.  Thanks

Comment: oh me a derp ... `data:` is a jQuery "property" for the request ... you'd need to do `data: { data: dataURL},` if you want the server to "see" data

Comment: I keep getting "An error occurred trying to load the resource" in the web inspector

Comment: even after the above fix?

Comment: with $.ajax({

   type: "POST",

   url: "user_group_start_paperwork_esign2.php?group_id=1389",
   data: { data: dataURL},
   

   //dataType: "html",

   cache: false,

   success: function(data){//console.log(data)

    

   }

  });

Comment: check the server logs for the cause of the error

Comment: Ok now it is adding a file to my images directory with 58b8ddad22a6a.png but there isn't anything in the file